# Javascript function not being found when Button is clicked to invoke it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have defined my OpenWin() function to handle opening the new window and pass params to it but when I compile it it says it is not defined.

```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         function OpenWin()
>             {
>                 var
> 
>                     Parms = document.getElementById('PassParmString').value;
> 
> 
>                 window.open("ViewerPane.aspx?prm=" + Parms,"_blank","left=20,top=20,width=1000,height=1140,toolbar=0,resizable=1")
>             }
>     </script>
```

And further down is the button script ...

```
>             <asp:Button ID="btnAuthenticate" OnClick="OpenWin()" runat="server" Height="44px" Style="z-index: 108;
>                 left: 716px; position: absolute; top: 243px" Text="Authenticate" Width="97px" />
```

Message:...

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'OpenWin' is not a member of
>   'ASP.default_aspx'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 38:             
>   top: 243px" Text="UserName :"> Line 40:
>    Line 42:
>
> Source File: C:\projects\Centauri_0.01\ASPXRPT\Default.aspx    Line:
>   40

Comment: Your problem is probablywith username textbox script. Change top:243" to top: "243px"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnClick` refers to server side events.
Change it to `OnClientClick` for javascript functions.

For more information, you should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

**EDIT :** As far as opening of the window is concerned try changing `_blank` with `''` like :

```
window.open("ViewerPane.aspx?prm=" + Parms,"","left=20,top=20,width=1000,height=1140,toolbar=0,resizable=1")
```

Comment: @Andrew : Would you mind accepting the answer, if it worked for you ?

Comment: Accepted, Thanks. Any ideas on the opening issue?

Comment: @AndrewMcLintock : Updated my answer, hope it works for you :)

Comment: No. Makes no difference. Weird!

Comment: Which browser are you testing against ? In firefox, you can use firebug add-on to track JS errors. Do you see some when you click the button ? Please post details, I think I can help you get around this, after looking at details.